# To make a copy of the file in the same folder with only date change - using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a report which needs to be sent out daily. Every morning, I manually using 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and make a copy of the report in a specific folder, then open the excel file and refresh the contents. 
To remove this everyday manual labor, I wrote a power shell script which could automate the task for me.

**Script:**

```
$OriginalDir = "C:\Users\101335\Google Drive\BI\Aditya\Daily Order Report"
$BackupDir = "C:\Users\101335\Desktop\Test"

$LatestFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $Originaldir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | 
Select-Object -First 1

Copy-Item -path "$OriginalDir\$LatestFile" "$BackupDir\$LatestFile"

Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir | Rename-Item -newname {"Daily Order Report _India_" +$_.CreationTime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".xlsx"}
$LatestFile1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | 
Select-Object -First 1

Copy-Item "C:\Users\101335\Desktop\Test\*.*" "C:\Users\101335\Google Drive\BI\Aditya\Daily Order Report"

Start-Sleep -s 2

Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir -Include * | remove-Item -recurse
```

**Problem:**

What I have tried to do is:

- copy the latest file from the Original folder
- copy it up to the backup folder
- rename it
- copy it back again to the original folder
- delete the file from the backup folder.

I have been able to pursue the steps up to renaming of the file with the current date, but I am not able to copy it back to the original folder.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're copying to a backup directory, renaming, copying back to original **and** then deleting from the backup directory, I don't know why you need to use a backup directory at all - You could just copy the file into the original directory with the new name.

Try:

```
$OriginalDir = "C:\Users\101335\Google Drive\BI\Aditya\Daily Order Report"
$LatestFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $Originaldir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
$LatestFileName = $LatestFile.Name
$LatestFileTime = $LatestFile.CreationTime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy")

Copy-Item "$OriginalDir\$LatestFileName" $("{0}\Daily Order Report _India_{1}.xlsx" -f $OriginalDir, $LatestFileTime)
```